# groovy insert statement Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

Tags: sql, groovy, insert

error message:

```
URI
/racetrack/readUserRole/index
Class
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
Message
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use
```

code:

```
a="col01"
b="col${usercol}"
c="col${rolecol}"
sql.eachRow("select $a,$b,$c from read_csv where col01=? and col${usercol}!=? ", [file.name,""]) {

    t="${it."$a"}"
    i="${it."$b"}"
    r="${it."$c"}"
    t.getClass() == String
    i.getClass()== String
    r.getClass()== String

    def list2=[t,i,r]
    println list2
    sql.execute('insert into read_user_role(version,roledata,textname,userdata)'+
            'VALUES (0,?,?,?)', list2)
}
```

the problem occurred at insert statement as error message, so how i suppose to fix this sql type issue?

Comment: can you cast explicitly?  e.g. `list2 = [t,i,r]*.toString()` ?

Comment: also your select there might be vulnerable to an sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Use the static methods on the [Sql](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) class to wrap your variable into a  type known to the database. For example, to wrap a `GString` as `varchar`, you can use:

```
import static groovy.sql.Sql.*

....

sql.eachRow("select * from foo where name = ${VARCHAR(myVar)}")
```